# Subtree selection with connect by

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchy

I have some hierarchic data, similar to this diagram
[image]

this is done for example in a table with a parent and child id

```
link_table
--------------
parent_id
child_id
```

for simplicity, the id's (sort of) from above would be like this:

```
parent_id    child_id
---------------------
1            11
1            12
12           121
121          1211
12           122
122          1221
122          1222
2            21
```

my challenge is this:

Given a selected node (122) - I need to return the tree that contains the (non cycling) root path (1 and 12 - but not 11), the selected item (122) and all further children (1221, 1222) and nothing from other trees (the original parent is a null for all trees)

I can write a normal connect by to start with the selected id and get the 'child tree'

and I can write a connect by to go upwards to the connect_by_root.

my question is: how do I combine these into one statement that returns a nice LEVEL and the nodes in the highlighted tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this combo of ideas: - thanks to all - I have upvoted

```
select id, depth, depth - MIN(depth) OVER()+1 lvl 
from (
SELECT parent_id AS id, depth
FROM   (
  SELECT parent_id, 1-LEVEL AS depth
  FROM   table_name
  START WITH child_id = 12
  CONNECT BY
       PRIOR parent_id = child_id
  ORDER BY LEVEL DESC
)
UNION ALL
SELECT child_id, depth
FROM   (
  SELECT child_id, LEVEL AS depth
  FROM   table_name
  START WITH child_id = 12
  CONNECT BY
         parent_id = PRIOR child_id
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY child_id
));
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to parse the tree using two recursive CTE :

-A first recursive CTE to parse the tree bottom up to find all ancestors

-A second recursive CTE to parse the tree top down to find all descendants

After that, you can simply union those two CTEs to get desired result.

For instance :

```
WITH 
ancestor(parent_id,child_id) AS (
  SELECT parent_id,child_id 
  FROM link_table
  WHERE child_id = 122
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT link_table.parent_id, link_table.child_id
  FROM link_table
  INNER JOIN ancestor ON
    ancestor.parent_id = link_table.child_id
),
descendant(parent_id,child_id) AS (
  SELECT parent_id,child_id 
  FROM link_table
  WHERE parent_id = 122
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT link_table.parent_id, link_table.child_id
  FROM link_table
  INNER JOIN descendant ON
    descendant.child_id = link_table.parent_id
)


SELECT parent_id,child_id FROM ancestor
UNION ALL
SELECT parent_id,child_id FROM descendant
```

[Try it online](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e23bdb6512058d391da48e1fed01b5e8)

**Edit :**

I noticed you also needed the node level within the hierarchy. I edited my query accordingly :

```
WITH 
/*Find all ancestors from the node 122. 
The node level is 0 for the node 122, and decreased by one for each parent*/
ancestor(parent_id, child_id, node_level) AS (
  SELECT parent_id,child_id, 0
  FROM link_table
  WHERE child_id = 122
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT link_table.parent_id, link_table.child_id, ancestor.node_level -1
  FROM link_table
  INNER JOIN ancestor ON
    ancestor.parent_id = link_table.child_id
),
/*Find all descendant from the node 122. 
The node level is increased by one for each level of descendant*/
descendant(parent_id,child_id,node_level) AS (
  SELECT parent_id,child_id, 1 
  FROM link_table
  WHERE parent_id = 122
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT link_table.parent_id, link_table.child_id, descendant.node_level +1
  FROM link_table
  INNER JOIN descendant ON
    descendant.child_id = link_table.parent_id
),
/*the following query allows us to find the whole branch of the hierarchy
However, the node level is negative for the parent*/
hierarchy_branch (parent_id, child_id, node_level) AS (
SELECT parent_id,child_id,node_level FROM ancestor
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT parent_id,child_id,node_level FROM descendant
)
/*Using the previous query, we can now calculate the corrected node level by 
substracting the node_level from the root from each node_level.

The root_node level is found using min within a window function :
   MIN(node_level) OVER()

the uncorrected node_level is still here for information
*/
SELECT parent_id,child_id, node_level, node_level - MIN(node_level) OVER()+1 corrected_node_level   
FROM hierarchy_branch
ORDER by corrected_node_level
```

[Try it online](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=33b929c148ef88a091ec63434dd7c530)

Comment: yes - thank you - however, i am struggling with preserving the LEVEL psuedocolumn so that the actual tree structure is maintained...

Comment: I just edited my answer, could you see if this what you need?

Comment: As a side note, and because I have wasted some time trying to figure it out, be aware that  level is a reserved keyword in Oracle.

Comment: i am adapting this one for real life - appreciate the contribution, i'll vote soon. thanks!

Comment: So i think the example i made is not showing one case - and that is that the tree structure gets destroyed by the ordering of the level ( which is correct - thanks ) - essentially this solution leaves me with the same problem that i get when i do 2 connect by queries and union them, the tree structure does not survive.

Comment: Could you provide some more details? I cannot really figure out the issue. What do you mean exactly by "the tree structure does not survive"?

Comment: OK Sorry, struggled with how to describe it,  simplest is say we select 1.2 as the starting node instead of 1.2.2.  in this case we will also include the branch 1.2.1 and 1.2.1.1.  HOWEVER in the final ordering, 1.2.1.1 will come after 1.2.2 (wrong branch)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need some sort of structure similar to the hierarchyid datatype from SQL Server? [hierarchyid](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6048/sql-server-hierarchyid-data-type-overview-and-examples/)

Comment: Please, have a look at the following fiddle. I tried to replicate the feature as best as I could, though I had to use some nasty tricks. If it fits your requirements, I'll edit my answer accordingly : [try it online](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8edfd942170ff48737e5a1317c20fc04). Be aware that the tree structure will be generated on the fly, and is not guaranted to have the same numerotation with each successive call.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT parent_id AS id, depth
FROM   (
  SELECT parent_id, 1-LEVEL AS depth
  FROM   table_name
  START WITH child_id = 122
  CONNECT BY
       PRIOR parent_id = child_id
  ORDER BY LEVEL DESC
)
UNION ALL
SELECT child_id, depth
FROM   (
  SELECT child_id, LEVEL AS depth
  FROM   table_name
  START WITH child_id = 122
  CONNECT BY
         parent_id = PRIOR child_id
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY child_id
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (parent_id, child_id) AS
SELECT 1,   11   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1,   12   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12,  121  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 121, 1211 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12,  122  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 122, 1221 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 122, 1222 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   21   FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | DEPTH |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | -1 |
> | 12 | 0 |
> | 122 | 1 |
> | 1221 | 2 |
> | 1222 | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=0fa83e8d45c9a1873bb38189467f6263)*

Comment: Thanks.  This is closest to what I started with - I think maybe wrap this in another layer and recalculate the depth(level) as @Random User shows below

Answer (score 0):

With your sample data defined in WITH clause as **tbl**:

```sql
WITH
    tbl AS
        (
          Select '1'    "PARENT_ID",    '11'    "CHILD_ID" From Dual Union All
          Select '1'    "PARENT_ID",    '12'    "CHILD_ID" From Dual Union All
          Select '12'   "PARENT_ID",    '121'   "CHILD_ID" From Dual Union All
          Select '121'  "PARENT_ID",    '1211'  "CHILD_ID" From Dual Union All
          Select '12'   "PARENT_ID",    '122'   "CHILD_ID" From Dual Union All
          Select '122'  "PARENT_ID",    '1221'  "CHILD_ID" From Dual Union All
          Select '122'  "PARENT_ID",    '1222'  "CHILD_ID" From Dual Union All
          Select '2'    "PARENT_ID",    '21'    "CHILD_ID" From Dual 
        ),
    param AS 
        (  Select :Parameter_Id "PARAM", LEVEL "LVL", SubStr(:Parameter_Id, 1, LEVEL) "LVL_PARAM"  From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= Length(:Parameter_Id)  )
--  Here is the main SQL
SELECT  p.PARAM "PARAM", t.PARENT_ID "PARENT_ID", t.CHILD_ID "CHILD_ID"
FROM    tbl t
INNER JOIN
    param p ON(
                  ( p.LVL = Length(t.PARENT_ID) AND SubStr(p.PARAM, 1, p.LVL + 1) = t.CHILD_ID )
              OR
                  ( p.LVL =Length(t.PARENT_ID) AND SubStr(t.CHILD_ID, 1, Length(p.PARAM)) = p.PARAM )
              )
--
--  R e s u l t   -  FOR :Parameter_Id=122
--
--       PARAM PARENT_ID CHILD_ID
--  ---------- --------- --------
--         122 1         12       
--         122 12        122      
--         122 122       1221     
--         122 122       1222 

--
--  R e s u l t -   FOR :Parameter_Id=121
--
--       PARAM PARENT_ID CHILD_ID
--  ---------- --------- --------
--         121 1         12       
--         121 12        121      
--         121 121       1211    
  
--
--  R e s u l t -   FOR :Parameter_Id=11
--
--       PARAM PARENT_ID CHILD_ID
--  ---------- --------- --------
--          11 1         11     

--
--  R e s u l t     -   FOR :Parameter_Id=21
--
--       PARAM PARENT_ID CHILD_ID
--  ---------- --------- --------
--          21 2         21
```

The **param** CTE generates levels that are used to select the data you asked for (straight from **tbl** CTE). Resulting column named PARAM should probably be excluded from Select statement. Regards...
**Correction**
Randy noticed my mistake in the answer. The sql was limited in depth by Inner Join ON clause (p.LVL = Length....). To remove limitation it should be **p.LVL <= Length......** This means some row multiplications so the DISTINCT keyword is needed as well as Order by clause. Below is corrected code with the results.

```sql
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        p.PARAM "PARAM",
        t.PARENT_ID "PARENT_ID", t.CHILD_ID "CHILD_ID"
FROM    tbl t
INNER JOIN
    param p ON(
                  ( p.LVL <= Length(t.PARENT_ID) AND SubStr(p.PARAM, 1, p.LVL + 1) = t.CHILD_ID )
              OR
                  ( p.LVL <= Length(t.PARENT_ID) AND SubStr(t.CHILD_ID, 1, Length(p.PARAM)) = p.PARAM )
              )
ORDER BY
    t.CHILD_ID, t.PARENT_ID 
--
--  R e s u l t   -  FOR :Parameter_Id=12
--
--       PARAM PARENT_ID CHILD_ID
--  ---------- --------- --------
--          12 1         12       
--          12 12        121      
--          12 121       1211     
--          12 12        122      
--          12 122       1221     
--          12 122       1222
--
--
--  R e s u l t   -  FOR :Parameter_Id=1
--
--       PARAM PARENT_ID CHILD_ID
--  ---------- --------- --------
--           1 1         11       
--           1 1         12       
--           1 12        121      
--           1 121       1211     
--           1 12        122      
--           1 122       1221     
--           1 122       1222
```

Comment: Thanks.  When you run this against '12' then you should get the entire tree downwards, not just one node level down.  I also am struggling with the LEVEL psuedocolumn

Comment: @Randy: My mistake, sorry. I posted the correction. Inner Join's ON clause had wrong condition. Now it works as expected. There was no LEVEL struggling - just the bad join condition. Regards...